# What does this Haskell Data.Maybe function do?

Tags: haskell

I would like to ask if you know what this function does:

```
hasUnassigned :: [Int] -> Bool
hasUnassigned board = isJust $ elemIndex 0 board
```

I found this function online and I plan to use it to help draw Sudoku game solutions.

Please could you explain to me how it works?

Answer (score 11):

`elemIndex` searches for the first argument in the second argument, which is a list. It returns a `Maybe Int` - `Just` the index if the element is found, `Nothing` otherwise.

`isJust` returns true if a `Maybe` value is a `Just`, false if it is a `Nothing`.

In other words, this is a very awkward way of testing whether `board` contains 0. A better way is

```
hasUnassigned board = 0 `elem` board
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand better with your explanation.

Now I'm saying is that if you know how to implement another function to do the same but without using Data.Maybe, since I have not ever used.

Comment: @user1885332 His last solution doesn't use `Data.Maybe`.  `elem` is from the prelude.

Answer (score 2):

`elemIndex` has signature `a -> [a] -> Maybe Int`. When applied to `x` and a list `list`, it gives us `Just i` if `x` appears for the first time in `list` at position `i`. If `x` is not in `list`, we get `Nothing` instead.

The outer function, `isJust`, takes a `Maybe a` and tells us if it's of the form `Just whatever` or `Nothing`. `hasUnassigned` thus checks to see if there's a `0` in the board list.